# Extended keyword in sql query does not work

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Microsoft SQL Server 2012. I have query

```
"SELECT COUNT(sessionid) as callshandled,
CAST((EXTEND(startdatetime, YEAR TO SECOND) + " + 
WBUtils.getOffsetInMins() + " units minute) AS DATE)  
As 
date FROM contactcalldetail 
WHERE 
contactdisposition=2 
AND 
startdatetime >= '"
+ WBUtils.getGmtFromLocal(sDate) + 
"' AND startdatetime < '" +
WBUtils.getGmtFromLocal(eDate)
+ "' GROUP BY 2 ORDER BY 2"
```

> WBUtils.getOffsetInMins() return int, 
>       WBUtils.getOffsetInMins() and WBUtils.getGmtFromLocal(eDate) - String.
>   When I try execute it I get:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TO'.
```

Could you please help me understand what mean keyword "extended" and what is wrong in this query. As I this query was not written by me and as I understand  worked good before. I am not sure what SQL Sserver version was used before.

Comment: Can you tell us the expected output of this query and some sample data?

Comment: There is no such keyword in "sql server". It's Informix or PL/SQL

Comment: yes, you are right, this is syntax for db Informix, is it possible write new query instead current that will work in Informix and ms sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0510roy/

> The EXTEND function adjusts the precision of the DATE argument and
>   returns the appropriate DATETIME.

In T-SQL you'd cast the date to get the different type

```
DECLARE @date date = '12-21-05';
SELECT @Date as date, CAST(@Date AS datetime) AS datetime;
```